# PHPMailer SMTP ERROR: command failed

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

My code works when i use gmail has host, but for this project i have to use office365.com and i receive errors i do not know what to do with :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;           // enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->IsHTML(true);

    $mail->Host     = "smtp.office365.com";         // SMTP server
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                      // sets the prefix to the servier
    $mail->Port       = 587;                        // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL 
    $mail->Username   = "username";     // username
    $mail->Password   = "password";             // password

    //works with this (gmail)
    //$mail->Host     = "smtp.gmail.com"; // SMTP server
    //$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";          // sets the prefix to the servier
    //$mail->Port       = 587;            // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL 
    //$mail->Username   = "username";  // GMAIL username
    //$mail->Password   = "password";            // GMAIL password

    $mail->setFrom('someEmailAdress');
    $mail->addReplyTo("someEmailAdress");

    $mail->AddAddress('someEmailAdress');

    $mail->Subject  = $_POST['ActivityType']." ".$_POST['DealerName'];
    $mail->Body     = $message;
    $mail->WordWrap = 400;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;    
    $mail->Send();
```

this is the error i get

```
12014-12-22 18:15:39    SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 BY2PR05CA022.outlook.office365.com
    Microsoft ESMTP MAIL Service ready at Mon, 22 Dec 2014 18:15:39 +0000
2014-12-22 18:15:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO 192.168.1.53
2014-12-22 18:15:39 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-BY2PR05CA022.outlook.office365.com Hello [24.37.210.58]

250-SIZE 78643200

250-PIPELINING

250-DSN

250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES

250-STARTTLS

250-8BITMIME

250-BINARYMIME

250 CHUNKING
2014-12-22 18:15:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2014-12-22 18:15:39 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 SMTP server ready
2014-12-22 18:15:39 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2014-12-22 18:15:40 SERVER -> CLIENT:
2014-12-22 18:15:40 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed:
SMTP connect() failed
```

been tryin to figure out whats going on, but theres really not much to search upon with the "general" error of quit command failed. Especially when gmail works fine, could it be on office365 side?

Comment: Make sure you're using latest PHPMailer - your code example looks like it's based on an old version, though I can't see anything particularly wrong! As it's failing at the point when encryption starts, it's worth checking that your OpenSSL PHP extension is installed correctly and enabled in php.ini. Also try `SMTPDebug = 4` to get more detailed low-level connection info.

Answer (score 0):

btw outlook is most restricted of them all specially when it comes to html emails which is the one u have set in ur options ,try first to send to something like gmail ,maybe yahoo but again it have some restriction but gmail works everytime without any probs ,u can also use something like **fakesmtp** to catch the sent email.

Comment: I know its working with gmail, i even posted it in my question if you read it (its in the commented code).

that being said, i understand why outlook would restrict this, buts its such a pain.

Comment: i did read it but didn't notice it was the code for the gmail attempt not a phpdoc sorry for that ,anyway try something like mailchimp or mandrill ,i know that both serves kinda different purpose but give it ago maybe it fix ur problem (actually one of the selling points of mailchimp is it works even with outlook ,but i haven't tried that yet though).

Answer (score 0):

sorry can't comment yet but try these

https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/189

or may be a selinux thing
http://osticket.com/forum/discussion/77982/resolved-smtp-office365-issue